# Can I know the namespace of my k8s Pod only by looking at its IP?

Tags: kubernetes, ip, devops, kubernetes-namespace

I have a list of ips of pods in a `k8s` cluster. I want to check what pods are from my namespace, without doing the following:

- Getting all pods from my namespace using kubectl
- Describing each pod to get its ip
- Checking using O(n^2) if each ip from the list if one of the ips in the namespace

Any ideas what can I do?

I didn’t try doing it yet, from my experience it is possible but it will be long.